# Assigning values to a df$column based on another column in the same df

Tags: r

```
df2 <- data.frame(Mean = c(.5,4,2.3,1.2,3.7,3.3,.8), Numbers = "NA")


for(i in 1:length(df2$Mean)){
        if(df2$Mean[i] <= .5) {
        df2$Number[i] = 0
        }           
        else if(df2$Mean[i] > .5 & df2$Mean[i] < 1.5){
        df2$Number[i] = 1
        }
        else if(df2$Mean[i] > 1.5 & df2$Mean[i] < 2.5){
        df2$Number[i] = 2
        }
        else if(df2$Mean[i] > 2.5 & df2$Mean[i] < 3.5){
        df2$Number[i] = 3
        }
        else {
        df2$Number[i] = 4
        }
    }
```

This works! However when I try to make a function out of it and call the function it dosen't work. I save the function file as "df2type.txt":

```
type <- function(df2){
for(i in 1:length(df2$Mean)){
        if(df2$Mean[i] <= .5) {
        df2$Number[i] = 0
        }
        else if(df2$Mean[i] > .5 & df2$Mean[i] < 1.5){
        df2$Number[i] = 1
        }
        else if(df2$Mean[i] > 1.5 & df2$Mean[i] < 2.5){
        df2$Number[i] = 2
        }
        else if(df2$Mean[i] > 2.5 & df2$Mean[i] < 3.5){
        df2$Number[i] = 3
        }
        else {
        df2$Number[i] = 4
        }
}
}
```

I invoke the function as:

```
source("df2type.txt")
type(df2)
```

Could you please tell me why the function is not working?

Thank you so much!

Comment: There are several problems with your code that suggest you may be very new to R. It should be beneficial to start with an introduction to the language such as http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`genotype` changes the copy of `AllSamples` that exists inside the function. When this function ends, that internal copy is destroyed (along with your changes to it); the original version of it (in your global workspace, most likely) is unchanged. If you make your function return `AllSamples` and then overwrite the original with the return value, that would work.

```
genotype <- function (AllSamples){
    for(i in 1:length(AllSamples$Mean.Regression)){
        ...
    }
    AllSamples
}
```

Then it would be called like

```
AllSamples <- genotype(AllSamples)
```

A more idiomatic approach would be to not change the data.frame in `genotype`, but to just create the new column (as a vector), return that, and assign that to the column of `AllSamples`.

```
genotype <- function (AllSamples){
    CopyNumber <- rep(0, length(AllSamples$Mean.Regression))
    for(i in seq_along(AllSamples$Mean.Regression)){
        if(AllSamples$Mean.Regression[i] < .5) {
            CopyNumber[i] <- 0
        } else if(AllSamples$Mean.Regression[i] > .5 & AllSamples$Mean.Regression[i] < 1.5) {
            CopyNumber[i] <- 1
        } else if(AllSamples$Mean.Regression[i] > 1.5 & AllSamples$Mean.Regression[i] < 2.5) {
            CopyNumber[i] <- 2
        } else if(AllSamples$Mean.Regression[i] > 2.5 & AllSamples$Mean.Regression[i] < 3.5) {
            CopyNumber[i] <- 3
        } else {
            CopyNumber[i] <- 4
        }
    }
    CopyNumber
}
```

which would be called as

```
AllSamples$CopyNumber <- genotype(AllSamples)
```

The real, real way to do this is to use vectorized functions rather than explicit loops.

```
genotype <- function(AllSamples) {
    cut(AllSamples$Mean.Regression,
        breaks = c(-Inf, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, Inf),
        labels = FALSE) - 1
}
```

which you call as

```
AllSamples$CopyNumber <- genotype(AllSamples)
```

Comment: Hi Brian, Thank you so much. I will now try it. Sorry changed the code above again to make it simpler. However I get the point. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Hi Brian, It works perfectly. Thanks. I am now going to try to do it via vectorized function like you suggested. I have a couple of questions and they may sound very basic but just to clear up my doubts: 1. Vectorized functions are functions like which() or cut() that work on whole vectors..right? 2. Seems like the cut() only works with one vector AllSamples$Mean.Regression. How is the resulting vector getting populated? Cheers!

Comment: Ok I think I see how its populated. The cut function creates a virtual vector somewhere in memory according to and corresponding to each element of AllSamples$Mean.Regression. That vector is then returned by the function and gets assigned to the dataframe. Am i correct?

Comment: @user1079898 That is correct. `cut` returns a vector which `genotype` subtracts 1 from and then itself returns. "Anonymous" is a more technical term than "virtual," though.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Brian! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Missing bracket at: rep(0, length(AllSamples$Mean.Regression)

Answer (score 4):

```
df$Number <- findInterval( df$Mean, c( seq(0.5, 3.5, by=1) , Inf) )
```

There was an edge case where df$Mean = 3.5 that was not covered by your definition. My method gives it a 4.

The `findInterval` function is really doing something very similar to the `cut` function, except it returns a numeric value rather that a factor. It sets up a bunch of intervals and tells you which interval each item would fall into.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you yesterday, but I wanted to respond to you when I understood whats going on with the findInterval function so I don't sound stupid. Thank you so much for answering my question yesterday. Eventhough I still don't understand how the findInterval function works I took a more traditional approach to help me solve this particular problem. However I have run into another issue when running the function as described above. Thanks a bunch!