# Adding a new column in R data frame with values conditional on values of another column

Tags: r, dataframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assigning values to a df$column based on another column in the same df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737146/assigning-values-to-a-dfcolumn-based-on-another-column-in-the-same-df)

Suppose I have the data frame:

```
table<- data.frame(population=c(100, 300, 5000, 2000, 900, 2500), habitat=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

Now I want to add a new column table$size with the values 1 if population< 500, 2 if 500<=population<1000, 3 if 1000<=population<2000, 4 if 2000<=population<3000, 5 if 3000<=population<=5000

I only know how to create a column with a binary TRUE/FALSE outcome conditional on the values in another column , e.g.

```
table$size <- (table$population<1000)
```

But I'm not sure to do it to get different numbers for different conditions. Can anyone provide help on this?

Comment: Please format your question better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all don't call a `data.frame` `table`, because `table` is a base function.

You can use `findInterval`:

```
df <- data.frame(population=c(100, 300, 5000, 2000, 900, 2500), 
                 habitat=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
v <- c(-Inf,500,1000,2000,3000,5000)
df$size <- findInterval(df$population,v,all.inside = TRUE)
  population habitat size
1        100       1    1
2        300       2    1
3       5000       3    5
4       2000       4    4
5        900       5    2
6       2500       6    4
```

I used `all.inside = TRUE` since you wanted to define 5000 as size 5 and I assume values cannot be greater than that. If they can, you could use something like

`v <- c(-Inf,500,1000,2000,3000,5001,Inf)`.

Comment: +1: I think `findInterval()` is always more tidy than `cut()` for these problems. Just FYI though, I don't think that the base function `table()` gets overwritten by calling a data frame "table" (in other words, you would still be able to *use* the `table()` function) but calling a data frame "table" does lead to distracting code for those experienced with R.

Comment: As a follow up to my previous comment, this is a good Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6135868/1270695

Comment: You are correct, but this is a slippery slope. If you use base function names for data objects it is just a small step to use them for user defined functions.

Comment: Your solution is very efficient and goes directly to the heart of the problem. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a function for your mapping. Thus including your different bins:

```
mysize <- function(x){
  if(x<500)
   return(1)
  if(500 <= x & x < 1000)
    return(2)
  if(1000<=x & x<2000)
    return(3)
  if(2000<=x & x<3000)
    return(4)
  if(3000<=x & x <=5000)
    return(5)
  else
    return(NA)
}
```

Then you can apply this function to your population column and add the needed new column:

```
table$population.bin <- sapply(table$population, mysize)
table
```

Comment: This is just ugly and most likely quite slow with bigger datasets. You should at least use `ifelse`, which is vectorised.

Comment: I agree your solutions is nicer. Didn't know about findInterval function until now.

Comment: It is not exactly easy to find these functions. If you edit your answer to use `ifelse` instead of `if` and `sapply` you get an upvote from me.

Comment: I should just have googled "find interval r" :-/

Comment: I thinks it's better to leave my naive answer as it is and ask the user to accept yours. By doing so, others might benefit from my learning process.

Answer (score 2):

so long as you can deal with 5's being any number <5001 instead of <=5000, you probably just want the cut function with labels.

```
# look at the help window
?cut

# initiate your table
table <- 
    data.frame(
        population = c( 100 , 300, 5000, 2000, 900, 2500) , 
        habitat = 1:6
    )

# create a new column with the desired cutpoints
table$size <- 
    cut( 
        # input data
        table$population , 
        # cut points
        c( -Inf , 500 , 1000 , 2000 , 3000 , 5001 ) , 
        # label values (character strings work too)
        labels = 1:5 ,
        # interval closed on the right?
        right = FALSE
    )
```